# How to make containing window/view resize as NSCollectionView gains or loses items?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

In my OSX app I have a NSCollectionView. When I add more items than the view can fit, the view and window don't resize automatically to fit all the content.

How can I make it happen?

For example: I have a view that can fit 5 items to be visible. I add 3 more items and the view would extend to the right / bottom adding these 3 new items to the right / second row.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this. Part of the reason is hinted at in your question:

> … the view would extend to the right / bottom adding these 3 new items to the right / second row

Well, which would/should it do, extend to the right or extend down? There's no one correct response, so the collection view has no way to decide this on its own.

Basically, when you add or remove items, you will need to compute the desired size of the collection view and resize the containing view(s) and/or window to accommodate it.

The calculation would look something like this:

```
// This part only need to be done once
NSCollectionViewItem* collectionViewItem = [[[NSCollectionViewItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"IconViewItem" bundle:nil] autorelease];
NSSize itemSize = collectionViewItem.view.frame.size;

NSUInteger count = collectionView.content.count;
NSUInteger itemsPerRow;
if (count * itemSize.width < maximumDesiredWidth)
    itemsPerRow = count;
else
{
    itemsPerRow = floor(maximumDesiredWidth / itemSize.width);
    if (itemsPerRow == 0)
        itemsPerRow = 1;
}
NSUInteger rowsNeeded = (count + itemsPerRow - 1) / itemsPerRow;
if (!rowsNeeded)
    rowsNeeded = 1;
NSSize collectionViewSize = NSMakeSize(itemsPerRow * itemSize.width, rowsNeeded * itemSize.height);

NSSize scrollViewSize = [NSScrollView frameSizeForContentSize:collectionViewSize
                                      horizontalScrollerClass:nil
                                        verticalScrollerClass:nil
                                                   borderType:collectionView.enclosingScrollView.borderType
                                                  controlSize:NSRegularControlSize
                                                scrollerStyle:collectionView.enclosingScrollView.scrollerStyle];
```

Now you need to resize the scroll view to accommodate the collection view. And you may need to resize any containing views and the window. How you do that depends on whether you're using auto layout or not. If you're using auto layout, it further depends on exactly how you've set up the constraints.

If may be sufficient to compute the difference between `scrollViewSize` and `collectionView.enclosingScrollView.frame.size` and adjust the window's size by the same amount. Usually, you'd also adjust the window's origin, too, to keep the top of the window in the same place. That is, if you add *N* to the height of the window, you'd subtract *N* from the Y coordinate of the origin, too.

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for your response, there is this example I found that does what I need but I don't see how they do it...I thought it comes for free with NSCollectionView https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I'm familiar with that example, but I don't see it resizing the window to fit more icons. It just scrolls. If you resize the window, the scroll view and the collection view get resized along with it, which matches your question's original subject line (which I edited) but not the body of your question (which is why I changed it). Is that what you really meant to ask?

Comment: Oh I see...I just thought it's all related and works in the same manner

Comment: Is this still the recommended way to pull this off? Or is there a way to do it with Auto Layout constraints?